# Are their public IP ranges which don't belong to any country?

Tags: ip, ipv6, internet, ipv4

I've been working on project and we use IP geo-location using an API to identify user's country. The legacy code has an edge case when there is no country information for a particular IP. I have been planning to remove this, since from understanding, every public IP on the internet has a country. If the API didn't return country for a particular IP, it means their database is not good, and we should switch to a better service

My question is, are their public IP ranges on the internet which doesn't belong to any country? What are the example of those?

Comment: So you would rather have _wrong_ information instead?

Comment: Where from do you have the information that every IP belongs to a country? I would rather say that no IP belongs to a y specific country. Example s of IPs that certainly don't is satalite links, or anycast addresses.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Not sure what do you mean by "wrong". If every IP belong to a country, there can't be a wrong value?

Comment: @NiKiZe Can you please expand on it? Like some articles, list of IP ranges so that I can test them? Can anycast initiate connection to a remote server as a client?

Comment: What you probably mean is **"Are there ip addresses that have not been delegated to one of the Regional Internet Registries and aren't associated with a specific geographic location?"**

Comment: It is not possible to determine a country for many IP addresses from publicly available information. Most of these data providers are making guesses, and they are often wrong.